# Facing issue with implementing local storage in redux

Tags: local-storage, redux

I am implementing localStorage in redux

```
export const loadState = () => {

  try{
      const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('state');
      if(serializedState === null){
        return undefined;
      }
      var result = JSON.parse(serializedState);
      delete result['router'];
      return result;

  }
  catch(err) {
    return undefined;
  }
};

export const saveState = (state) => {
   try{
      const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
      localStorage.setItem('state', serializedState);
    }
  catch(err)
   {
     return undefined;
   }
};
```

I am setting initial state and  updating state like this

```
initialState =  loadState();

const store = createStore(
  makeRootReducer(),
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    ...enhancers
  )
)

store.subscribe(() => {
  saveState(store.getState());
});
```

The store object before refresh

http://pastebin.com/hnaMYvDJ

and after refresh

http://pastebin.com/LYFdF8Qk

The issue i am facing is on page refresh the state does not persist all the keys but only key which is present in the current route. What i am doing wrong(edited)
is there any particular channel where i should ask this question

Comment: Looks like you had a look at Dan Abramovs new egghead course ;-) What do you do with this `delete result['router'];`line of code? Can you share your reduces to get a better understanding of the structure of the store?

Comment: if we do not delete route then we are not allowed to move to any other route. Edited question and provided store object and yes the implementation is based on Dan Abramovs new egghead tutorial :D

Comment: hmm difficult - can you verify if the complete store (including the "home" section) is saved into local storage (log in subscribe method)? When do you recover the store from local storage? Are there any other actions which get triggered after loading the persisted store?